# How to check if value in a cell is in the range. Based on that assigne different 'scores' to new column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, for-loop, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
orderID       Amount
   0          340.00
   1          200.00
   2           10.00
   3          500.00
   4          700.00
```

I want to 'score' each order amount on condition if the amount is in the designated range or if it is 'outside' how far from the range.

My range is: `low = 300`, `high = 500` if in this range, I want to assign score = 100.
If the value in `Amount` column is outside the range I want to apply a scoring function like this:

```
if Amount > high:
    df['score'] = 100 - (Amount - high)/100
else:
    df['score'] = 100 - (low - Amount)/100
```

I tried such a snippet, but it takes extremely long time (millions of rows):

```
 def pricing_function (df, column_name):
         for l in range(0,df.shape[0]):
             if (df[column_name].iloc[l] <= high and df[column_name].iloc[l] >= low):
                 df['score'][l] = 100
             elif df[column_name].iloc[l] > high:
                 df['score'][l] = 100 - (low - Amount)/100
             else:
                 df['score'][l] = 100 - (low - Amount)/100
```

And then apply the function as:

`df['score'] = df.apply(pricing_function(df= my_df, column_name = 'Amount'))`

As a result, I would like to have dataframe like:

```
orderID      Amount    score
   0         340.00     100     
   1         200.00      99
   2          10.00      71
   3         500.00     100
   4         700.00      80
```

Iterating over each cell using for-loop takes ages and I could not find a solution for that on StackOverflow. 
I tried using:

`df['score'] = my_df['Amount'].between(low, high, inclusive = True)`

This gives True/False values for the values inside/outside the range. I can change the booleans later to 1/0 and 100/0 in the last step, but I still have problem applying my scoring_function efficiently.

Comment: your `Amount` differs in input/output

Comment: You're right. corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) what is use for avoid multiple `np.where`:

```
low = 300
high = 500
m1 =  df.Amount > high
#inclusive = True is by default, so omited
m2 = df['Amount'].between(low, high)

a = 100 - (df.Amount - high)/100
b = 100 - (low - df.Amount)/100

df['score'] = np.select([m2, m1], [100,a], default=b)
print (df)
   orderID  Amount  score
0        0     340  100.0
1        1     200   99.0
2        2      10   97.1
3        3     500  100.0
4        4     700   98.0
```

Answer (score 2):

With **[`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)** function:

```
df['score'] = np.where(df.Amount.between(low, high), 100,
                       np.where(df.Amount > high, 100 - (df.Amount - high)/100,
                                                  100 - (low - df.Amount)/100))
```

Interactively:

```
In [46]: df['score'] = np.where(df.Amount.between(low, high), 100, np.where(df.Amount > high, 100 - (df.Amount - high)/100, 100 - (low - df.Amount)/100))

In [47]: df
Out[47]: 
   orderID  Amount  score
0        0   340.0  100.0
1        1   200.0   99.0
2        2    10.0   97.1
3        3   500.0  100.0
4        4   700.0   98.0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
low, high = 300, 500

df['score'] = np.where(df['Amount'].between(low, high), 100,
                       100 - np.maximum(low - df['Amount'], df['Amount'] - high)/100)

print(df)

   orderID  Amount  score
0        0   340.0  100.0
1        1   200.0   99.0
2        2    10.0   97.1
3        3   500.0  100.0
4        4   700.0   98.0
```

The logic is as follows:

1. If within the range, choose 100.
2. If above the range, `df['Amount'] - high > 0 > low - df['Amount']`; and vice versa. We take the maximum to ensure only the positive value is used.